# compile ffmpeg with x264

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I need ffmpeg with hardware acceleration.
I am compiling ffmpeg following this guide:
https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/eb45d2e22afec7534f4a117d15fe6d89

x264 never works after compile.
I follow the official guide, adding "--enable-shared", compile again, still no luck.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Simply installing libx264-dev does not work as well.

> $ ldd ~/bin/ffmpeg | grep x264 libx264.so.155 => not found

Does anyone know how to make x264 work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is there not any error message when you configure ffmpeg?

Or you can command ffmpeg, and show the configuration like

```
configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
```

Maybe you can try install x264 from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VCPKG to install ffmpeg with x264 support this project is avaliable on GIT.
Its a straight forward installation using VCPKG.

how to use vcpkg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRnjahwxZ8A&t=114s